# Fix Import numpy syntax error with __file__

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.__file__ 'C:\Adrian\Python37\Lib\numpy-1.11.2\numpy\__init__.py'
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

what should my last command be for there to be no error? It worked once, I don't remember how I did it. I may have added a command after import numpy as np.

Comment: What are you even trying to do here?

Comment: I do not have a file named numpy.py.    
My exact steps are: in Python, Open C:\Adrian\Python37\Lib\numpy-1.11.2\setup.py, I run this module:    
>>>     
=========== RESTART: C:\Adrian\Python37\Lib\numpy-1.11.2\setup.py ===========    
Running from numpy source directory.    
>>> import numpy as np    
>>> list_int = [8, 3, 34, 111]    
>>> a_int = np.array(list_int)    
Traceback (most recent call last):    
File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>    
a_int = np.array(list_int)    
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'array'

Comment: Add these comments to the question please

Answer (score 0):

You haven't installed the numpy before importing,i don't know the IDE you using but run " i had same problem but i realised and fixed it